# Передача значений в инпут VUE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, vue.js

У меня есть форма VUE которая отправляет данные в firebase. 
С помощью скрипта я передаю в инпут значения 
var phone = url.searchParams.get("phone");
document.getElementById('th-userPhone').value = phone;

Работает все нормально в инпуте есть value с данными 
Но при отправке приходит пустое поле
Когда ввожу текст сам в input, то отправляет нормально

Comment: Как насчет показать нам ваш код?

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вам vue, если вы заполняете инпут таким способом?
Используйте v-model, как указано в документации к vue и подобных проблем не будет.

Comment: Да, я использую v-model, а как я могу так передать значение с ссылки?

Comment: Выполнить ваш код внутри vue компонента и не пихать значение в инпут, а обновлять модель.